# Прикрепить footer к низу страницы (sticky footer)

Tags: javascript, html, css

На сайте есть несколько страниц, на которых мало информации, и нужно приклеить футер к низу страницы. Перепробовал много способов, но всегда есть проблема с background страницы. Получаеться ситуация как на рис. 1, а нужно чтоб было как на рис 2.
И высота футера неизвестна, так как меняеться изминением размера страницы

Рис. 1

[image: Рис. 1]

Рис. 2

[image: Рис. 2]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прижимать footer всегда к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

[image: Поддержка FlexBox]

Способ 1

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 auto;
          flex: 1 auto;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #ffc0cb;
}
footer {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
header,
main,
footer {
  width: 80%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>content</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

---

Про [Css Calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
Поддержка Calc - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Способ 2

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header,
main,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
header,
footer {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
main {
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #ffc0cb;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>content</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Comment: в обеих случчаях нужно знать высоту футера,да?

Comment: @Wepster через flex не нужно, через calc высота должна быть фиксированным

Answer (score -1):

например позиционируешь подвал position:absolute; и ставишь left:0; bottom:0;

background-size:cover; для бэкграунда

Comment: content не тянется.

Comment: @ Jean-Claude min-height пробовал для контента?

Comment: например, min-height 50vh... ну или по ситуации, если не использовать flexbox.

Comment: И высота футера неизвестна, так как меняеться изминением размера страницы